# Calculating length of polygon in GeoPandas

Tags: python, polygon, geopandas, area, length

For example, to calculate the area is like this:

```
df['area'] = df['geometry'].area
```

How do we find the length of the perimeter?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Same way as area but:

```
df.geometry.length
```

or

```
df['geometry'].length
```

See [GeoSeries.length](http://geopandas.org/reference.html#GeoSeries.length):

> Returns a Series containing the length of each geometry.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [GeoSeries.length](http://geopandas.org/reference.html#GeoSeries.length) for this. Note that geopandas uses Shapely that is crs agnostic. You will need to reproject your geodataframe to a crs in a unit that makes sense.

```
import geopandas as gpd

gdf = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres'))
gdf.crs
gdf["perimeter"] = gdf["geometry"].length
gdf.head()
# As you can see, the perimeter is calculated in the unit of the crs e.g. degrees length. not very meaningful.

# lets reproject and try again

ECKERT_IV_PROJ4_STRING = "+proj=eck4 +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs"

gdf_eckert4 = gdf.to_crs(ECKERT_IV_PROJ4_STRING)
gdf_eckert4["perimeter"] = gdf_eckert4["geometry"].length
gdf_eckert4.head()
```

Note that the length of a polygon (perimeter) is arbitrary depending on the resolution of your polygon. 
It is also known as the [coastline paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coastline_paradox)

[Notebook with example](https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/gist/rutgerhofste/3b3c84089b051919d34aaa2f2f3cc747)